What is the purpose of pipes that are sticking out of the Boeing 747 FWD Cargo door?
I went to visit an Aviation museum recently and noticed these pipes that are sticking out of a Boeing 747 in the FWD Cargo bay...
What are these pipes called and what is the purpose of them?


This is not just 'a' 747, it's N7470, the 747 prototype on display at the Museum of Flight in Seattle. As such there may be any number of items fitted to the airframe for testing purposes. These pipes don't appear on production aircraft, so I expect that they're something to do with testing carried out only on the prototype.

Curious.  Based on the flythrough at the Boeing Museum website, they appear to be located on the starboard side, just forward and below the forward-most flight test water ballast barrel. So, how about drainage for those?
